# What is the difference between initializing array in C and not doing so?

Tags: arrays, c, initialization

I have created a code that will output the number of times you enter -1 for each digit.
I tried to declare with int count[10]; and int count[10]={0};. However, both the time of declaration and the time of initialization will produce proper results.
Could you tell me the difference between initializing at 0 and not doing so?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    
    int count[10];
    int i,num;

    while(1){
        scanf("%d", &num);
        
        if(num==-1){
            break;
        }

        if(num>=0 && num<=99){
            if (num<10){
                count[num]++;
            }
            else{
                count[num/10]++;
                count[num%10]++;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        printf("%d : %d\n", i,count[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Initializing is correct; not initializing is incorect. Initializing will **always** give the correct answer, not initializing will only give the correct answer at random times. Try compiling your code with full optimizations and not for debugging (or the compiler might try to be helpful and initialize to `0` anyway)!

Comment: If a variable is uninitialized, its value is indeterminate. Accessing an indeterminate value is undefined behaviour, which means the program could work as you expect today, print garbage tomorrow, and explode and kill everyone in the building next week (or do anything else, literally).

Comment: You also access indeterminate value from `num` whenever `scanf()` makes fewer than one conversion - __never__ ignore its return value.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't initialize `count[0]` (etc), its value is indeterminate. Since your code accesses an indeterminate value (e.g. with `count[num]++`), the fact that your code worked without initialization is a fluke, and it's not something you can rely on.

Comment: Accessing an indeterminate value in an array is never undefined behavior (due to the access), as an array cannot be declared `register`, so the last sentence of C 2018 6.3.2.1 2 never applies.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, It can be UB since it can be a trap representation, but I'll relax the wording anyway.

Comment: As I noted, the access of an indeterminate value does not have undefined behavior for the reason that an indeterminate value was accessed. It could have undefined behavior for other reasons, as any code can generally. If the indeterminate value has a trap representation, that is a different matter than the mere fact of accessing an indeterminate value. And, in a type for which the C implementation does not have any trap representations, an indeterminate value must be an unspecified value (an actual value); it cannot be a trap representation.